# Is there a way to give internet only to a virtual machine/virtualized application while not having an internet connection on the host?

Tags: virtualization, privacy

I'm thinking at this from the privacy perspective, so that we can control the extent of the snoopers intents on our computers, to limit their view to what is online only on the virtual machine running with internet so that the host is completely out of their scope. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely impossible.

Think of it this way:  all resources of the virtual machine come from the physical machine, RAM, Disk, CPU, and Network.

If the physical machines itself doesn't have this resource, there is no way the virtual machines can have this resource.

Comment: Although I upvoted, I would deem it possible for the host not to have an Internet connection and instead rerouted everything to the guest machine. Technically the host would have the resource, but wouldn't use it.

Comment: Yeah. you are right. you can route all network traffic to VM. but technically, the host have Internet connection in that case as well.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking at a crippled connection. Start internet on the host, save the route, delete the route, import the route in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You could, though, this would be tricky - You'd want to passthrough a network device directly to the VM, and the only real way to do this is through passing through a USB wifi, or network adaptor, and having networking completely turned off on the guest. While the USB layer is shared, actual networking is entirely on the guest. You can presumably confirm this with wireshark to be sure

I suppose VT-D and pci passthrough, and some hypervisors may be able to do this as well, but I've never really heard of anyone doing either of these for this reason